# PHP - if condition match exact value including decimal

Tags: php

i am trying to match exact number with decimal. i have tried following but doesn't work

tried following code, but doesn't work with decimal.

```
<?php
$number=1.23;
$numbers=1.28;

if (is_float($number)==is_float($numbers))
{
   echo 'matched';
}else{
   echo 'not matched';
}

?>
```

please check where i am doing mistake or it's totally wrong way to do that. i have check above in PHP sites.

Comment: You're comparing booleans.  Just use `$number === $numbers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`floatval`](http://php.net/floatval) (which returns the float value of the given variable) instead of [`is_float`](http://php.net/is_float) (which returns `true` if the given variable is a float and `false` if it isn’t).

Comment: Using floatval is not even necessary in this case. They are already floats. Just compare one to the other like normal.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make use of a strict matching operator `===` instead of `floatval` or `is_float`.

```
<?php
$number=1.23;
$numbers=1.28;
if($number === $numbers)
{ 
 echo "Matched";
}
else { echo "No Match"; }
```